# Bash compile curl as a builtin

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, wget, built-in

Someone know how to compile curl or wget in order to make a loadable builtin ? 
I wanted the same work as it is in the bash git source in the examples/loadables folder : [here](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/tree/master/examples/loadables).

But I have no idea to do so, or where to find it.

Could someone help me ? 
It would be very nice to load curl/wget to have best performance in one of my script.

Comment: It's unlikely that this will give noteworthy performance improvement. Why do you think it would?

Comment: You can't just compile them into loadable modules. *You* have to write a loadable module with that functionality, maybe using libcurl.

Comment: Ok, 1st i was thinking that if i enabled it as a loadable module, it would not create a new process (it's best for the load average, mostly when you've got a lot of curl calls).

Comment: 2nd, if it's needed to use libcurl I underestimated the work …. if it's hard to code it no problem i'll do without a loadable module, thx